# Using Python in Arcmap to partition strings

Tags: python, linestring

I have a title "Text that remains Proposed Thing to replace"

> var_a = New Text

I want the output to be

> "Text that remains Proposed New text"

Currently outputs this

> "(u'Text that remains ', u'Proposed', u' Thing to replace')"

Trying to add the var_a

```
b = a.partition('Proposed') + var_a
```

But get this error

> : can only concatenate tuple (not "str")
>   to tuple Failed to execute (LegendText).

```
# Loop through each text element in the map document
for textElement in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):

# Replace Title text
if textElement.name == "Title":

# With this text
a = textElement.text
b = a.partition('Proposed')
textElement.text = str(b)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [str.partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) returns a tuple, not a string. I think that's what's holding you up.

Comment: How can I convert it back into a string without it looking like this?                                                     "(u'Text that remains ', u'Proposed', u' Thing to replace')"

Comment: You don't want to convert the tuple to a string, you want to access the meaningful part of the tuple (the 3rd element), and replace that substring in the original string with the new string. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
new = "new text"
text = textElement.text
old = text.partition('Proposed')[2] # Get the 3rd element of the tuple, the part after "Proposed"
textElement.text = text.replace(old, new)
```